# Which container format for ProDVX F150

Tags: playback, codec

I need to produce a video that can be played by a ProDVX F150 (a small black box device which plays video from a flash card). It's hard to find real specs for this thing, but webshops say it does:

> Playback formats: MPEG1 (up to 8Mb/sec VBR),MPEG2 (up to 8Mb/sec VBR),MPEG4 (up to 8Mb/sec VBR),JPEG,MP3

Based on this (little) info, what container, video codec and audio codec would you recommend? The video is 576p PAL.

Unfortunately I don't have the device at hand for easy testing, otherwise I'd just hit-and-hope with various formats.